# Altering array while keeping a backup copy

Tags: c#

I have an array with 3 integers. I want to duplicate the array and change the first integer. For some magical reason, BOTH arrays get their first integer adjusted. I have no idea why this is happening and it's driving me crazy.

```
int [] numbers1 = {1, 2, 3}
int [] numbers2 = {3, 4, 5}

numbers2 = numbers1;
```

At this point I did a `System.Console.Writeline` to see both arrays are now {1, 2, 3}. So far so good.

```
numbers1[0] = 4;
```

When I'm doing a `System.Console.Writeline` I see BOTH arrays now look like {4, 2, 3}. I want numbers2 to stay the same.

Comment: wondering after so many well explained answers why you did not still accept the answer? Which point still not clear otherwise please mark appropriate reply as answer to help others. @biggetje

Comment: I'm sorry dude it's called going to bed... Logged in just now to read the answers. Maybe it's common to stay around when posting questions, if so I apologize. I'm new on this forum. I just tried to solve it myself after a whole day of programming, gave up, posted the question and decided to go for some much needed sleep, hoping I'd find a solution to my answer in the morning :-).  @immirza

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you are only passing a reference. The numbers in the array are stored in memory. When you reference an object in memory it points to that object. It does not create a new object in memory when referencing, so you need to clone the ints into another array so that it points to a different object in memory.

```
         numbers2 = numbers1;
```

You need to clone the arrays.

```
        numbers2 = (int[])numbers1.Clone();
```

As others have noted you can also use the .ToArray() method. This creates a copy of the items in the array.

```
       numbers2 = numbers1.ToArray();
```

Comment: Note this will only make a shallow copy of the array, if your objects in the array are classes with properties any changes to the properties of the objects in the array will show up in both arrays.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain At this point we should be talking about the difference between value types and reference types.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are a reference-type, regardless if the values of an array are value-types.

When you allocate an array you are creating a block of memory that the array variable points to. When you assign one array variable to another you are assigning the memory reference, not the values in the array. So both of your `numbers1` and `numbers2` arrays are pointing to the same set of values.

Now this should make sense. Imagine if you have an array with a million elements then every time you assigned or passed the array around you made a copy it would be an horrific performance issue.

So, you need to explicitly say when you want to copy an array.

The easiest way is to do this:

```
numbers2 = numbers1.ToArray(); // yes, this copies the entire array.
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this:

`numbers2 = numbers1;`

You are assigning the reference of first array to the second array. So it loses your original contents and start pointing to `numbers1`. If you want to copy few or all items of `numbers1` to `numbers2` then either use `Clone()` or `use loop to copy elements`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `.ToArray()` method? It will create new array not assign by reference `Array2= Array.ToArray();` [Click here for more about .ToArrray()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

try to use the `.ToArray();` or `Clone` its work for me

my suggestion is `.ToArray();`